# extract Grayscale from yuv in libjpeg

Tags: libjpeg, turbojpeg

On either TurboJpeg or the underlying libJpeg APIs - is there a simple function for extracting the Y component from the Ycbcr (after I've already read the image)?

I know I can loop over the data and extract the bytes. Isn't this already implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When decompressing/decoding, use the `TJPF_GRAY` format, it discards the colour information and only the Y (luminescence) remains.

See the [this part of the API](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/libjpeg-turbo/code/trunk/doc/html/group___turbo_j_p_e_g.html#ggac916144e26c3817ac514e64ae5d12e2aa5431b54b015337705f13118073711a1a) for reference, as well as [that part if you are willing to transform it](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/libjpeg-turbo/code/trunk/doc/html/group___turbo_j_p_e_g.html#ga132ae2c2cadcf64c8bb0f3bdf69da3ed), or [this function](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/libjpeg-turbo/code/trunk/doc/html/group___turbo_j_p_e_g.html#gada69cc6443d1bb493b40f1626259e5e9) if you are willing to decode it directly into a gray-scale image.

Comment: So, if I need both the YUV and the Y components, then I load it as TJPF_GRAY and then use tjTransform to get the Y component. Got it right?

Comment: `TJPF_GRAY` is equal to the Y component. If you need both, the YUV and the Y you got to decode it as YUV and do the transform with `tjDecodeYUV` to a "RGB" with 1 byte per pixel, the luminescence/gray/Y part.

Comment: And for that I need the new API 1.3.1

Comment: @mousomer you might maybe even need the version 1.4, but as it is backwards compatible there should be no problem upgrading it.

Comment: do you know where I can get the new 1.4? I can't find it at sourceforge. And the tjDecode is only in the 1.4 version.

Comment: @mousomer I'd recommend you to contact the maintainer (information@libjpeg-turbo.org) of the project, I have had some good experience the last time I contacted him.